# How to add more than one parameter to JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS

Tags: java, windows

I want to add the below parameters to JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS. Could anyone please help me how to add these?

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

If i add like above, will it work?

I tried setting the above command but i am not sure whether java picks these two parameters or not?

Experts help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Trying it is simple. Run a Java tool from the commandline and it will report whether it picked it up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tried setting this variable in my windows environment with Java 7 and doing `java -version` it gives me it set this variable , as shown as follows

```
C:\Users\ajduke>set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.e
ncoding=UTF8

C:\Users\ajduke>java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF
8
java version "1.7.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-ea-b145)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.0-b15, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: How can I define this in my java app? I don't want to recommends to all my clients to run above set command!!! Thanks

Comment: @MohTarvirdi depends on what kinda of application you running? is your app runninng in Tomcat Container, Spring container or Standalone app?

Comment: Note that there are no quotes (`'` or `"` around values of `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`). I tried to set it up with `"` first, but as a result all the values have been set to the first property only.

Answer (score 4):

Previous answer works for Windows. For unix based environment you should follow these steps:

1. Edit /etc/profile adding line:

   export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"'
2. Run

   source /etc/profile

This will set global environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS for all users immediately.

Answer (score 4):

In case only the first argument is picked up: **DON'T USE QUOTES**! Just the arguments:

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xms128m -Xmx512m
```

---

In my case (Windows), only the first argument was picked up and reported to be invalid, since I used

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m"
```

and starting any java app results in:

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Xms128m -Xmx512m"
> Invalid initial heap size: -Xms128m -Xmx512m
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.